# How animate character size?

Tags: javascript, game-engine, game-physics, craftyjs

I'm trying to make simple js game using crafty.js.

I have character that need to be more wide when it hit something, samurai with a sword.

What can i do to make right animation. I have it for example 20x20 in default and walking state, but it need to be 30x20 when it hit.

If will animate that width, samurai will change it's position to the left/right a bit. How can i do that right way?

Has anyone an example or useful article link?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the _x value of the entity to its previous value after changing the width so that the samurai does not move left/right?

You could do it like this:

`var previous_x = Crafty("Samurai").x;`

`Crafty("Samurai").attr({ w: 30 });`

`Crafty("Samurai").attr({ x: previous_x });`

If this does not work, go to the [official Crafty forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/craftyjs)